# VeraCrypt: Windows as decoy, Linux as hidden OS

Tags: linux, windows, veracrypt

I am currently running Windows 10 and want to install Linux Mint as hidden OS while using Windows as decoy. Is this possible with VeraCrypt?
I couldn't find anything via Google, only that Linux can't be used as decoy OS which is not the case here.

Comment: It was possible with Truecrypt.